# Is there any Facebook share plugin?

Tags: facebook

I always used this :

```
<script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.google.com" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

and I never see an "official plugin" that made the same "effect". Why? Is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook Share Button is now **deprecated**, but you can still use `sharer.php`

**Javascript:**

```
function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
        var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
        var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' + descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width='+winWidth+',height='+winHeight);
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/', 'Fb Share', 'Facebook share popup', 'http://goo.gl/dS52U', 520, 350)">Share</a>
```

- JS Gist: https://gist.github.com/Stichoza/4942775
- Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/

Comment: but while sharing iam not getting the title and description that is passed. What to do for getting the title that we have passed????

Answer (score 2):

Facebook already provides a set of plugins that you can check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/). Basically you can use the Like plugin.

But you can also use the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), here is an [example](http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed).

Comment: how can I use this? How related it to any button?

Answer (score 1):

This used to be the official share plugin.

It's since been deprecated in favor of the [Send Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send) or if your app is authenticating users, the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

Comment: I'm looking for the share button, not send button :O

Comment: The share button is deprecated and is being evaluated for complete removal. See the comments between me and Igy (a FB employee) on this SO thread. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13088242/facebook-application-php-post-to-friends-wall/13090168#comment17794586_13090168