# Facebook share not bringing picture

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to make a facebook share button, using the Javascript SDK, and this is the code I am using:

```
$(function() {
  $('.facebook-share').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      link: SOME_VALID_LINK,
      picture: "https://netstars-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/staging/image/artwork/185/Screen_Shot_2013-06-25_at_2.07.21_PM.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJPC2ZNIXV535QU6A&Signature=lKS8UdWSDd8k5iFJxCFThTJnp8Y%3D&Expires=1380217515",
      name: "Screen",
      caption: "Please star my Image on Netstars.",
      description: "Some "
    }, function(response){});
  });
});
```

Everything is working as expected (link, description, name, caption), except for the picture (it is not being shown). If I copy and paste the link on a browser, the image is there.

What I am missing?

Thanks!

I've checked the live demo on [Is there any Facebook share plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085564/is-there-any-facebook-share-plugin) and the image sharing isn't working neither.

Comment: _“If I copy and paste the link on a browser, the image is there.”_ – I’m only getting an XML response telling me “Access Denied” and
“Request has expired” …

Comment: Did you copy the entire link?

Comment: Yes, of course. The link itself contains a parameter `Expires=1380217515`, and that timestamp was about twenty minutes ago.

Comment: I'm probably out-of-date, but I thought it got the share image from meta tag data in the target page HTML?

Comment: Not when you explicitly specify a (different) picture with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the facebook share link, I would recommend you to use the Facebook Share Dialog that facebook offers. Try this,

```
<html>
     <body>
        <div>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.google.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.turtlegardens.org/blog/wp content/uploads/2012/10/FBShare.jpg" width="150px" height="60px"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JsFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/EYxTJ/133/

For more details : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/

Comment: If you check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/) it is using the fb sharer with an image and the image is not showing

Comment: The share dialog does not take any additional arguments besides the URL to share any more, but instead gets the info from the document itself via Open Graph meta tags.

Comment: Yes, because Facebook itself fetches it from the URL. But the OP wants to specify an image at the time of making the post, and that’s not possible with the Share dialog, only with the Feed dialog.